# Angular pwa push notification is not working for the other devices rather than PC browser

Tags: angular, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I have implemented the push notification using `Angular v15` PWA service worker and `.Net v7` but push notification is not working in other devices example: mobile except pc

how to implement push notifications for all the device without node included

I used the `ng-push-notification` npm package to do my task but it works only on pc browser and it is not `pwa` npm package

I need a complete solution that how can I implement to all the devices without node

Comment: WebPush only work on iOS with Safari 16.4 AND when the app is install of the springboard.

Comment: can you explain me how can i implement the push notification in angular pwa service worker